# Stem Spanish words in isolation to validate that they are "words" in SpaCy's (or any) dictionary

Tags: nlp, spacy, stemming, lemmatization

I have a list of 20,000 words. I want to know which of the 20k words are "weird" in some way. This is part of a text cleaning task.

`Albóndiga` is fine, `huticotai` is no Spanish word I know... neither is `56%$3estapa`

This means I must compare declined/conjugated words in isolation to some source of truth. Everyone recommends SpaCy. Fine.

Somehow, though, using the code below and a test file with a few dozen words, spaCy thinks they are all "ROOT" words. Si hablas castellano, sabrás que así no es.
technically, I don't want to lemmatize anything! I want to stem the words. **I just want to pair down the 20k-long wordlist to something I as a Spanish-speaking linguist can look at to determine what sorts of of crazy desmadre (B.S.) is going on.**

Here is an example of the output I get:

- trocito NOUN ROOT trocito
- ayuntamiento NOUN ROOT ayuntamiento
- eyre NOUN ROOT eyre
- suscribíos NOUN ROOT suscribío
- mezcal ADJ ROOT mezcal
- marivent VERB ROOT mariventir
- inversores NOUN ROOT inversor
- stenger VERB ROOT stenger

Clearly, "stenger" is not a Spanish word, though naïvely, spaCy thinks it is. Mezcal is a NOUN (and a very good time). You get the picture.

Here is my code:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("es_core_news_sm")

new_lst = []
with open("vocabu_suse.txt", 'r') as lst:
    for i in lst:
        # print(i)
        new_lst.append(i.strip())

for i in new_lst:
    j = nlp(i)
    for token in j:
        print(token.text, token.pos_, token.dep_, token.lemma_)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty confused about what you're trying to do here. To be clear, my understanding is that your main objective is to find what words in your list aren't junk, and  you tried using lemmatization to check them, and the lemmatization results seem wrong.

> This means I must compare declined/conjugated words in isolation to some source of truth. Everyone recommends SpaCy. Fine.

spaCy is great for many NLP tasks but dealing with lists of words with no context is really not something it's intended for, and I don't think it's going to help you much here.

### Finding Real Words

To address your main problem...

First, to find out what words aren't junk, you can use a wordlist you trust or a relatively normal large corpus.

If you don't have a wordlist you trust, you can see if the words are  in the vocab of the spaCy models. spaCy's vocabs can include junk words, but since they're built by frequency it should only include common errors. This [wordfreq repo](https://github.com/LuminosoInsight/wordfreq) may also be helpful.

To check if a word has a word vector in spaCy, in the medium or large models you can use [tok.is_oov](https://spacy.io/api/token#:%7E:text=is%20the%20token%20out-of-vocabulary%20(i.e.%20does%20it%20not%20have%20a%20word%20vector)%3F).

If you want to go from a corpus, use a corpus you have or Wikipedia or something, and discard words below a certain word count threshold. (I understand inflection makes this more difficult, but with a sufficiently large corpus you should still be finding real words with some frequency.)

### About the ROOT

The ROOT tag is a dependency tag, not a tag of word form. In a dependency parse of a sentence the ROOT is typically the main verb. In a sentence of one word, that word is always the root.

I think you want the `tag_` attribute, which is a detailed language-specific POS tag. The `pos_` attribute is a coarse-grained tag designed for multi-lingual applications.

### About Lemmatization

I don't understand this statement.

> technically, I don't want to lemmatize anything! I want to stem the words.

Lemmatization is almost always better than stemming. "Stemming" usually refers to a rule-based process that works based on token patterns, so for your particular problem it won't help you at all - it'll just tell you if words have common word endings or something. You could have a word like "asdfores" and a stemmer would happily tell you it's the plural of "asdfor". Lemmatizers are often based on databases of words that have been checked so it's closer to what you need.

In either case, spaCy doesn't do stemming.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to clean up a list of words, you could use a PoS tagger that works with a dictionary, such as [Freeling](https://nlp.lsi.upc.edu/freeling/node/1). I think that the output analysis level `morfo` could be suitable for your needs. As an example:

```sh
cat input.txt | analyzer -f es.cfg --flush --outlv morfo --noprob
```

Output:

```
trocito trocito NCMS000 -1

ayuntamiento ayuntamiento NCMS000 -1

eyre

suscribíos suscribir+os VMM02P0+PP2CP00 -1

mezcal mezcal NCMS000 -1

marivent

inversores inversor AQ0MP00 -1 inversor NCMP000 -1

stenger
```

You should check the entries without a tag assigned ("eyre", "marivent", "stenger"), not present in the dictionary.

Please note that the tool includes some kind of "guessing" for malformed words, so maybe you should pay attention to entries including '_' in their lemma as well.

```sh
$ echo "hanticipación" | analyzer -f es.cfg --flush --outlv morfo --noprob
```

Output:

```
hanticipación h_anticipación NCFS000 -1
```